# Web Services: How do I detect the endpoint that sent the message

Tags: java, web-services, rest, soap

I am working on an application that processes both SOAP and REST messages from a large number of applications.  We use Camel to route the messages via SOAP to other locations.  I now have a requirement to take action on the messages based on the originating location.  Is it possible to determine the URI from where the message was sent?  I'm still learning web services and none of my Google searches have given me anything.

In debugging the code I have found a `fromEndpoint` object in the Camel Exchange object.  In my testing I am using SoapUI.  The `fromEndpoint` object contains "direct://MessageName".  Will this contain the correct from information when it comes from another server?  If that is true, is it possible to configure SoapUI to put in the correct information?

***Additional information ***

The WSDL and XSDs that dictate the format of the messages are controlled elsewhere.  The change process for them is long and complicated.  (We already have a request in to make a simple change to the WSDL.  They are saying 1 to 2 years before it will be approved.) The messages are generated by a number of different applications.  Yeah, it's a nightmare.  So we have to find ways to make it happen within what we currently have.  I was really concerned that a solution may not be possible.  I just find it hard to believe that when a message comes in there's not a way that the infrastructure (SOAP and/or REST) can't tell me where it came from without having to physically put it in the message itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally came across the answer to my problem here.  You can get a WebServiceContext injected into the Controller object.  With this you can obtain the HttpServletRequest and therefore the remote host and remote address for that transaction.

I added

```
@Resource
WebServiceContext wsContext;
```

To my Controller class.  Then added a getServletRequestObject method

```
protected HttpServletRequest getServletRequestObject() {
    MessageContext msgContext = wsContext.getMessageContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) msgContext.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST);
    this.log.info("Request from {} at {}", request.getRemoteHost(), request.getRemoteAddr());
    return request;
}
```

When I need request information I call that method.

It works great!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add additional exchange header or property, put the endpoint name in the property just before sending message. So that it can be retrieved in next endpoint.

Comment: That would normally be what I would have done.  However the format of the message that is coming to me is dictated by a controlling organization and changes are almost impossible to get approved.  You know how that goes.  Sometimes we in IT are limited by what our ultimate customer dictates.

Answer (score 0):

I can find nothing that allows me to obtain the URL of the originating server.  So at this point rather than leave the question unanswered I am updating it with the apparent answer.  NO this is not possible.